# how to use regex in BeautifulSoup

Tags: regex, beautifulsoup

as the pictures below.

[image]

I want to grab `li` with the `class=splist_1_1`, And skip `class=splist_1_1 s special_sub`.

I use `re.compiler` with `BeautifulSoup`. But it's not work.

```py
title=soup.find(attrs={'class':re.compile('splist_1_1(?!special_sub)')})
```

Comment: welcome to `StackOverflow` Community, I've corrected some mistakes on your question. Kindly please have a look into [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and **please** post the `HTML` source as a code not an `image` so we can manually `copy/paste` to test. that's will make it easier for both of us.

Comment: Thanks a lot~This is my first post. Not very understand how to edit~

Comment: your `HTML` is malformed so the output is confusing, could you please edit the question and include the `HTML` source code ?

Answer (score -1):

```py
for item in soup.select("li.splist_1_1"):
    if item.find(class_='special_sub'):
        continue
    else:
        print(item)
```

Or

```
r"<li[^>]+?class=\"splist_1_1\"[^>]+>"
```

Verify it online : [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/KAi0Ke/2)